# Web Scraping through Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am just a beginner at Python.

I am trying to scrape data from a site and have managed to write the below code.

However, I am not sure how to proceed ahead as I am unable to get the `href` tags so that I can go to each listing & get the data. I am also not very well aware of HTML Tags, so I suspect that I have not identified the tags properly.

Here is my code :

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = []
for i in range(1,5):
    pages = "https://directory.singaporefintech.org/?p={0}&category=0&zoom=15&is_mile=0&directory_radius=0&view=list&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&featured_only=0&feature=1&perpage=20&sort=random".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)

Data = []
for info in urls:
    page = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'sabai-directory-title'})
    hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]
```

The above code is producing hrefs as a blank list.
Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine, the class that you're looking for just doesn't exist on those pages. For example, substituted sabai-directory-title class with comment-reply-link after inspecting https://directory.singaporefintech.org/hello-world/?category=0&zoom=15&is_mile=0&directory_radius=0&view=list&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&featured_only=0&feature=1&perpage=20&sort=random and got results when i added print statements

Comment: i am sorry, but i am not too good at Identifying Tags, i did inspect the element and found that the hrefs which i need to click to have that particular listing opened up, is under the div class sabai-directory-title tag. below is the HTML tag, please suggest the solution :-

Comment: <a href="https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/amaas" title="AMaaS" class=" sabai-entity-permalink sabai-entity-id-43 sabai-entity-type-content sabai-entity-bundle-name-directory-listing sabai-entity-bundle-type-directory-listing">AMaaS</a>

Comment: what's the URL to the page that has the a tag you reference?

Comment: https://directory.singaporefintech.org/
This is the site i am trying to scrape data from. It has 27 pages, and each listing's information is visible when i will click on each listing.

Comment: Oh i see - what you need to do is first get the div with that class and then get the a tags you need and extract the href. The "sabai-directory-title" class is not in an "a" element/tag, but in a div element. It also seems like the base URL you have set as the "pages" variable that you append to urls may be incorrect as it's different than the link you provide in your comment below (https://directory.singaporefintech.org/ has div elements with the "sabai-directory-title" class).

Comment: the list Urls is giving me the exact urls of the pages i need to loop on, from page 1 to 27, The Url - "directory.singaporefintech.org" is the base & the url -"https://directory.singaporefintech.org/?p={0}&category=0&zoom=15&is_mile=0&directory_radius=0&view=list&hide_searchbox=0&hide_nav=0&hide_nav_views=0&hide_pager=0&featured_only=0&feature=1&perpage=20&sort=random" is giving me the links to the pages from 1 to 27.
The list Urls is generating the correct output, however the links list is blank , :(

Comment: oh no it seems like the website does something funny. So try this, go to https://directory.singaporefintech.org/, then go to page 2. Then click refresh. It's a completely different page and this is the page you get when you try to scrape for some reason. This is why you're having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have made few changes to code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

urls = []
for i in range(1,5):
    pages = "https://directory.singaporefintech.org"
    urls.append(pages)

Data = []
hrefs = []
for info in urls:
    page = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('div', attrs ={'class' :'sabai-directory-title'})
    for link in links:
        Data.extend([a['href'].encode('ascii') for a in link.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text])
pprint (Data)
```

output:

```
     ['https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/silent-eight',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/moolahsense',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/myfinb',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/wefinance',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/quber',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ayondo-asia-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ceo-1',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/acekards',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/paper-ink-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/alpha-payments-cloud',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/samurai-fintech-singapore-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/corris-asset-management-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/fundmylife',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mooments',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/venture-capital-network-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/junotele_',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mobilecover',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cherrypay',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/toast',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cashdab',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/silent-eight',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/moolahsense',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/myfinb',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/wefinance',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/quber',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ayondo-asia-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ceo-1',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/acekards',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/paper-ink-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/alpha-payments-cloud',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/samurai-fintech-singapore-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/corris-asset-management-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/fundmylife',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mooments',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/venture-capital-network-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/junotele_',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mobilecover',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cherrypay',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/toast',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cashdab',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/silent-eight',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/moolahsense',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/myfinb',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/wefinance',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/quber',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ayondo-asia-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ceo-1',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/acekards',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/paper-ink-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/alpha-payments-cloud',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/samurai-fintech-singapore-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/corris-asset-management-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/fundmylife',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mooments',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/venture-capital-network-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/junotele_',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mobilecover',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cherrypay',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/toast',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cashdab',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/silent-eight',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/moolahsense',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/myfinb',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/wefinance',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/quber',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ayondo-asia-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ceo-1',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/acekards',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/paper-ink-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/alpha-payments-cloud',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/samurai-fintech-singapore-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/corris-asset-management-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/fundmylife',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mooments',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/venture-capital-network-pte-ltd',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/junotele_',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/mobilecover',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cherrypay',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/toast',
     'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cashdab']
```

Is this the data output you are expecting.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Yes, it is giving the output you have mentioned, but how can i loop it to get the information from various listing on various pages, 
I am sorry but i am badly stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

You can scrap links using CSS selector. Selector `div.sabai-directory-title a` will find any `<a>` tags inside `<div>` tag with class `sabai-directory-title` (I updated the URL, yours was giving me error pages):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get('https://directory.singaporefintech.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

hrefs = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('div.sabai-directory-title a')]

pprint(hrefs)
```

This will print:

```
['https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/silent-eight',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/incomlend',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/bizgrow',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/makerscut',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/soho-fintech',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/dxmarkets',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/fundrevo',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/money4money',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/onelyst',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/hearti-lab',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/samurai-fintech-singapore-pte-ltd',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/ceo-1',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/arcadier',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/plmp-fintech-pte-ltd',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/cash-in-asia',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/grc-systems',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/sendexpense',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/jinjerjade',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/hatcher',
 'https://directory.singaporefintech.org/directory/listing/fintech-consortium']
```